How to use multiple filters & parameters in a DAX expression for Power BI paginated report
I have the following requirement:
Design an .rdl report (multipage) that is hosted in Power BI. The report must have several interactive filters enabled that a user will select to filter out only required information.
I was able to implement one filter with the following DAX expression:
DEFINE VAR __DS0Core = 
    FILTER( SUMMARIZE(
        'User List',
        'User List'[Description],
        'User List'[Email],
        'User List'[FacilityName],
        'User List'[FirstName],
        'User List'[LastName],
        'User List'[SiteName],
        'User List'[Username],
        'User List'[LastLogin]
     ),
        PATHCONTAINS(@Program, 'User List'[Description])
    )

EVALUATE
    __DS0Core

ORDER BY
    'User List'[Description],
    'User List'[Email],
    'User List'[FacilityName],
    'User List'[FirstName],
    'User List'[LastName],
    'User List'[SiteName],
    'User List'[Username],
    'User List'[LastLogin]


Where @Program is a parameter defined on the report
I am stuck now because it seems that PATHCONTAINS doesn't take more than one argument. I need to implement 3 more filters:  FacilityName, SiteName, and LastLogin
I just started leaning DAX 2 days ago and seems that my t-SQL experience isn't easily transferable to DAX. Any help would be appreciated.

DAX demystified. ;) I used && to provide multiple path conditions.
DEFINE VAR __DS0Core = 
    FILTER( SUMMARIZE(
        'User List',
        'User List'[Description],
        'User List'[Email],
        'User List'[FacilityName],
        'User List'[FirstName],
        'User List'[LastName],
        'User List'[SiteName],
        'User List'[Username],
        'User List'[LastLogin]
     ),
   (PATHCONTAINS(@Program, 'User List'[Description])) && 
   (PATHCONTAINS(@FacilityName, 'User List'[FacilityName])) &&
   (PATHCONTAINS(@SiteName, 'User List'[SiteName])) &&
   (PATHCONTAINS(@LastLogin, 'User List'[LastLogin]))
    )

EVALUATE
    __DS0Core

ORDER BY
    'User List'[Description],
    'User List'[Email],
    'User List'[FacilityName],
    'User List'[FirstName],
    'User List'[LastName],
    'User List'[SiteName],
    'User List'[Username],
    'User List'[LastLogin] 


